# parse facebook json javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, json

I am using javascript api to get facebook comments.

i am getting the following json result , but how can i parse them to use on my page ?

```
  {
      "id": "1234567891_2823098717038_3160191",
      "from": {
        "name": "User",
        "id": "1234567891"
      },
      "message": "comment only...",
      "can_remove": true,
      "created_time": "2012-05-05T07:43:11+0000"
    },
    {
      "id": "1234567891_2823098717038_3160281",
      "from": {
        "name": "User",
        "id": "1234567891"
      },
      "message": "just another comment...",
      "can_remove": true,
      "created_time": "2012-05-05T08:14:17+0000"
    },
    {
      "id": "1234567891_2823098717038_3160336",
      "from": {
        "name": "user2",
        "id": "56265654845454"
      },
      "message": "congratz dear :)",
      "can_remove": true,
      "created_time": "2012-05-05T08:29:05+0000"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "next": "http://link.dddd"
  }
}
```

How can i loop through this and display the contents ?

**jQuery solution is acceptable.**

Thank you.

Comment: I think you're missing part of your JSON response

Comment: copy and paste that JSON in any JS editor and you'll see what I mean. It looks like the beginning of the document is chopped off.

Comment: @MK_Dev its working now [that json result is coming from facebook,better you do a complaint to them + i am sorry if there is a common human error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JQuery.parseJSON`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: I tried a search on this matter before ,i know about this method ,but i dnt know how its gonna work or its not working...

Comment: please edit your question with the code you tried and did not work.

Comment: i managed it with a loop , no need of jQuery.I accepted you because i got a `-` award ..keep it up !

Answer (score 0):

assoc_data = jQuery.param(response); //where response is your json

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "submit_fb_data.php",
  data: assoc_data,
  success: function(data) {

```
//etc
```

}

});

- make sure you use a >=1.4 jquery version